# use GCM to talk between iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, google-cloud-messaging

So I'm on a team working on a cross-platform app using GCM.
The Android and iOS Team each has it's own GCM Sender ID and Server API Key.
Each platform can register and get a token. 
Each platform can successfully use GCM to talk to matching hardware : iOS -> iOS and Android -> Android...

The problem is we can't talk cross platform iOS -> Android and vice versa!?!?  I get a "MismatchSenderId"...

What am I missing?
I've tried using the Android Sender ID to register on iOS and that won't let me register...

So I'm at a loss as to how I'm suppose to use GCM to talk from iOS -> Android?

Any Help??

Answer (score 0):

SenderID in GCM by definition ([here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key)):

> A unique numerical value created when you configure your API project
>   (given as "Project Number" in the Google Developers Console). The
>   sender ID is used in the registration process to identify an app
>   server that is permitted to send messages to the client app.

You can spot it in Developer Console at the top left corner besides the options list (API & Auth etc...)

This error is thrown because this SenderID does not match with the API key for the project. Meaning you are probably using the API key from another project and using another project number (SenderID). Please check that you are using the right values at right places.

About implementing GCM for cross-platform communication is fairly simple since it is now available to iOS by API. If that's not working out for you there are third party libraries to help with it as well.

Useful resources:
GCM [iOS implementation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client)
[Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) for PushNotification